# AVMetaDataObject.bounds to SwiftUI position?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two views. The parent view holds a `CameraFeed` `UIViewControllerRepresentable` which passes back the bounds of a `AVMetadataFaceObject`. I'm trying to draw overlays where that bounds should be. I'm getting kind of close, but my mappings aren't quite right. The `CameraFeed` passes back a scalar-style set of bounds and I'm *multiplying* my geometry reader by it.

- The X and the Y seem to be swapped? (orange square works wrong and blue square works better)
- The location doesn't QUITE line up perfectly.

Acknowledgements: Thanks to the HackingWithSwift [InstaFilter](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/instafilter-introduction) and [Hot Prospects](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/hot-prospects-introduction) examples, btw. They were very helpful to getting this far.

I do understand that there is a `CALayer` that I could draw on in the AV object, and if I went that way I could use the more [powerful Vision framework](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1163620-face-detection-tutorial-using-the-vision-framework-for-ios) but I was seeing if I could try this approach first. I also am aware that there is a `CIFaceFeature` I could be using too. Also, I don't have a TrueDepth front-facing camera to work with. I just wanted to see if I could hijack this seemingly simplest of solutions to make it work.

What am I missing about the how how the bounds of `AVMetaDataObject` work and approaches to doing the frame of reference transformation? Thanks in advance. [Full Code on GitHub](https://github.com/carlynorama/Masquerade/releases/tag/0.0.3)

```
struct CameraFeedView: View {
    @State var foundFace:CGRect?
    @State var geometryRect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    //@State var foundFaceAdjusted:CGRect?
    //var testRect:CGRect = CGRect(
    //           x: 0.44112000039964916, 
    //           y: 0.1979580322805941, 
    //           width: 0.3337599992007017, 
    //           height: 0.5941303606941507)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
            ZStack {
                CameraFeed(codeTypes: [.face], completion: handleCameraReturn)
                if (foundFace != nil) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .topLeading)
                        .position(
                            x: geometry.size.width * foundFace!.origin.x, 
                            y: geometry.size.height * foundFace!.origin.y)
                        
                    FoundObject(frameRect: geometryRect, boundsRect: foundFace!)
                        .stroke()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                let frame = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                geometryRect = CGRect(
                                origin: CGPoint(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY), 
                                size: geometry.size
                               )
            })
        })
        
    }
    
    func handleCameraReturn(result: Result<CGRect, CameraFeed.CameraError>) {
        switch result {
        case .success(let bounds):
            print(bounds)
            foundFace = bounds
            //TODO: Add a timer
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Scanning failed: \(error)")
            foundFace = nil
        }
    }

}

struct FoundObject: Shape {
    func reMapBoundries(frameRect:CGRect, boundsRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        //Y bounded to width? Really?
        let newY = (frameRect.width * boundsRect.origin.x) + (1.0-frameRect.origin.x)
        //X bounded to height? Really?
        let newX = (frameRect.height * boundsRect.origin.y) + (1.0-frameRect.origin.y)
        let newWidth = 100//(frameRect.width * boundsRect.width)
        let newHeight = 100//(frameRect.height * boundsRect.height)
        let newRect = CGRect(
              origin: CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY), 
              size: CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        return newRect
    }
    
    let frameRect:CGRect
    let boundsRect:CGRect
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.addRect(reMapBoundries(frameRect: frameRect, boundsRect: boundsRect))
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pawello2222 for the formating help!

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate space from the Camera is rotated by 90° clockwise to the viewfinder.

```
/// Metadata Coordinates
 3---0
 |   |
 |   |
 2---1

/// Screen-space Coordinates
 0------1
 |      |
 3------2
```

This explains why you have to swap x & y.

Additionally, when you receive a `AVMetadataObject`, it uses normalized values for its origin & size. This means that x, y, width & height will all be contained in the 0...1 range.

Finally, when you use the `View.position(x, y)` view modifier, be aware that SwiftUI uses a view's center when using this function, so you also need to account for that!

**With all this in mind**

When you want to map this `AVMetadataObject`'s coordinates to your screen-space coordinates, you need to account for the rotation, and then the scaling.

The first thing that needs to happen is fetching the correct bounds of the view that is going to contain the `AVMetadataObject`'s visual bounds. You were already almost there; you need to use `.frame(in: .local)`. There's no need to apply any other transformation.

```swift
.onAppear {
    geometryRect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
}
```

Then, you can actually start mapping the coordinates.

```swift
func mapMetadataObjectCoordinatesToLocalCoordinates(viewBounds: CGRect, objectBounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    // The object's width & height need to be swapped
    let width = viewBounds.size.width * objectBounds.size.height
    let height = viewBounds.size.height * objectBounds.size.width

    let x = viewBounds.size.width * (1 - objectBounds.origin.y)
    let y = viewBounds.size.height * objectBounds.origin.x

    return CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(
            // Account for the fact that the `View.position` view modifier uses the center of a view
            x: x - (width / 2),
            y: y + (height / 2)
        ),
        size: CGSize(
            width: width,
            height: height
        )
    )
}
```

Then, you can declare your view as such:

```swift
struct CameraFeedView: View {
    @State
    var metadataObjectBounds: CGRect?

    @State
    var viewBounds: CGRect = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                CameraFeed(codeTypes: [.face], completion: handleCameraReturn)
                if let bounds = metadataObjectBounds {
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .frame(
                            width: bounds.size.width, 
                            height: bounds.size.height
                        )
                        .position(
                            x: bounds.origin.x, 
                            y: bounds.origin.y
                        )
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewBounds = geometry.frame(in: .local)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func handleCameraReturn(result: Result<CGRect, CameraFeed.CameraError>) {
        switch result {
        case .success(let bounds):
            metadataObjectBounds = mapMetadataObjectCoordinatesToLocalCoordinates(viewBounds: viewBounds, objectBounds: bounds)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Scanning failed: \(error)")
            metadataObjectBounds = nil
        }
    }   
}
```

#### Going beyond

This code should allow you to draw a simple rectangle over detected metadata objects, however if the view finder is rotated or skewed, using a simple Rectangle won't cut it anymore. You'll need to draw a dynamic quadrilateral from the corners the `AVMetadataObject` gives you. Those will need to be mapped as well, but I'll leave that exercise up to you ;)

Comment: @carlynorama don't forget to upvote/select answer if it helped you 